# Por que no me lee toda la línea

Tags: c#

Quiero leer la información de una línea de texto  para guardarla en un datagrid, pero solo me lee una parte, guardo la información en  `var txt = File.ReadAllLines("path");`
Y guardo la información de la primera línea en un String `String info = txt[0];`
Uso un for para guardar la información en el datagrid y cada que haya una "," crea una nueva columna:

```
String palabra = "";

for (int i = 0; i < txt[0].Length; i++)
{
   if(info[i] != ',')
   {
      palabra += info[i];
   }

   if(info[i] == ',')
   {
      dataGridView1.Columns.Add(palabra, palabra);
      palabra = "";
   }
}
```

Pero solo me muestra una parte por ejemplo la línea es
ciudad,casa,edificio,terreno
y solo me muestra los primeros 3 y el último no siendo que es de la misma línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

```
var txt = File.ReadAllLines("path");
string info = txt[0];
var columnas = info.Split(',');

foreach(var col in columnas)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col, col);
}
```

Como bien ya tu haces obtienes la primera línea del fichero y utilizando la **función Split** obtienes un **arreglo de strings** utilizando como separador al caracter **','** donde cada elemento de este arreglo será cada palabra encontrada en la primera linea del fichero. Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** donde se irán añadiendo las columnas correspondientes.